# COD Black Ops Multiplayer: Did anyone try laying down a claymore ON the converyor belt in radiation?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I'm not at home right now so can't try this out right away. Me and my buddy were discussing ways of defense against the opposing team in domination on the Radiation Map. Players are aware that there is a conveyor belt inside one of the buildings and I've seen a lot of players use it to find a safe passage around the map to get to flag C.

If you plant a claymore on the conveyor belt (which would be awesome since the area is bathed in red light and the claymore lasers would be hard to see) does it move along with the belt?

For my sake, I hope not :) It would be a good way to score a kill.

Comment: I don't think you can plant a claymore (or any other item) on movables. Even if you did, it would move along with the conveyor belt. The best place to plant a claymore is directly in the first room on the corner, or as you enter the conveyor room, right or left, facing the doorway.

Comment: Bora, I went ahead and tried this yesterday and was surprised to see it worked :) The claymore stays put when you place it on the conveyor belt!

Comment: Coolest thing ever :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went ahead and tried it myself, eventually. You can lay a claymore on the belt and it stays put.